# create span of strong type from a vector of the underlying type

Tags: c++, c++20

If I have a strong type wrapper for example:

```
struct StrongType {
  double val;
};

std::vector<double> v;
```

Is there any valid way to view the underlying type vector as if it were the strong type?

For example something like the following but without undefined behavior (and without copying):

```cpp
std::span<StrongType> strong_span(reinterpret_cast<StrongType*>(v.data()), v.size());
```

Based on my understanding of the aliasing rules this is UB since `StrongType` is not *similar* to `double`.

Edit: The reason I'm asking this is because I am working on an abstraction layer over a third party library. The third party library gives data back in a format roughly equivalent to a `std::vector<double>` and in the higher level abstraction there is certain compile time data that should tagged via the strong time. An example of this would be the coordinate system (for point data) and memory location (i.e., cuda memory vs. host memory).

Comment: Too much time I didn't write code in C++. Try creating a variable StrongType and than check its address and the address of the field var. They should be the same (because var is the first element of a data structure). Even if it's not, you can simply register the difference and use it as an offset. You can use the resulting address as a double *, and access directly the value.
But remember it's just a hack. It's not recommanded to do something like that.

Comment: IIRC `StrongType` can have padding bytes (for whatever propose). so it may not be continuous double.

Comment: IIRC, The address of a structure ***has*** to be the exact same as the address of its first member.

Comment: @appleapple good point. I need to check if there are special rules for single member structs.

Comment: Technical answer: No, it is impossible. You never created a `StrongType` object, so you can never access anything through a `StrongType` pointer, doesn't matter how the pointer is obtained.

Comment: If you created a "strong type", then you presumably want it to be *strong*. That is to say, different from its conceptual underlying type. You don't get to pick and choose when a type is "strong". If it's "strong", then it is not its underlying type.

Comment: *"Is there any valid way to view the underlying type vector as if it were the strong type?"* - I don't mean to be harsh, even though the following may sound harsh. That quote is just mincing words. The same question has been asked repeatedly: can we pun a buffer as though it holds another type. The answer is still (and likely always will be) no, C++ doesn't support the notion.

Comment: You could however create your own `std::span` wrapper with iterators that when dereferrenced produces a `StrongType<T>`  - possibly with a reference to the original `T` and proxy member functions to access it.

Comment: [`std::span` wrapper example](https://godbolt.org/z/vcbE8Ybfs) - would that be a solution?

Comment: Why don't you do it the other way around: have `std::vector<StrongType>` and have a span of `double` wherever you need that? (I suppose you need the latter b/c of legacy code, cmiiw).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I suppose I could/should have rephrased to ask whether there are exceptions to the type punning/aliasing rules for the case where you have a type with a single data member for conversion to the type of the data member.

Comment: @TedLyngmo interesting idea. This solution does a copy which I was trying to see if I could avoid. Looks like there are no special rules for single member structs and I'll have to stick with copying the data at my API interface.

Comment: @JacobMerson For small types my idea may be worse than a copy since it keeps a reference to the original object. Then again, the `StrongType` wrapper will always be the same size just because it keeps a reference. It never creates this `StrongType` unless you dereference the iterator though and one may hope that the whole creation of the `StrongType` when passed as an argument to a function accepting only `StrongType`s will be optimized away. Haven't verified that though.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is to **construct** your `StrongType` objects on the fly.  Ted Lyngmo [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546359/create-span-of-strong-type-from-a-vector-of-the-underlying-type#comment129876446_73546359) code that does this with additional wrapper types, but a simple version can be implemented with just the Ranges library:

```
for(StrongType st :
    std::views::transform(v,[](double d) {return StrongType{d};})) …
```

The result is a **random-access** range, though not a contiguous one (since it doesn’t yield references), and its iterators are merely C++17 **input** iterators.

Comment: Can you really not just reinterpret here? If `StrongType` adds no padding, then any actual reading/writing will still happen through the (now-underlying) `double` right? It's not like we're reinterpreting to u64.

Comment: @Barry: There’s no `StrongType` object there (even implicit object creation isn’t able to summon one coexisting with the `double[]`), so you can’t access `val` through such a fictitious path.  You certainly can’t do pointer arithmetic with the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

There are no exceptions to the aliasing/type punning rules for the case presented with a class with a single data member for conversion to the type of that data member.

Therefore a data copy (possibly using memcpy or bit_cast) must take place to accomplish this.